# Room querying one to many relationship

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

How can we query all entities with their one to many relationship with Room?

Say we have a **User Entity**:

```
@Entity
class User(@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Long?, var name: String)
```

and a **Pet Entity**:

```
@Entity(foreignKeys = [(ForeignKey(entity = User::class,
    parentColumns = ["id"],
    childColumns = ["userId"],
    onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE))])
public class Pet(@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true),
    var name: String,
    var userId: Long?,
    @Ignore var user: User?)
```

Normally we would query all pets like this:

```
@Dao
interface PetsDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM pets")
    fun getAll(): Flowable<List<Pet>>
}
```

But how can we make it so that the **User** is attached to the **Pet** object automatically? Like the query would be:

```
@Dao
interface PetsDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM pets p JOIN users u ON u.id = p.userId")
    fun getAllWithUser(): Flowable<List<Pet>>
}
```

And then we could use **pet.user.name** without having to query the user separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `@Embedded` (resource: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Relation.html)

Comment: @Embedded would work pretty well to get the list of pet in a user, I don't really see how to get the user from the pet itself (other way around). Would you care to give an example with this use case?